# Calcute a chance that whole rectangle lays inside of the circle

Tags: geometry, statistics

We are given circle with radius 1. 
Point P lays somewhere on that circle picked from the uniform distribution.
$\{P_x^2+P_y^2 = 1\}$
Point Q as well was randomly picked from the uniform distribution and lays inside the circle
$\{Q_x^2+Q_y^2 \le 1\}$
Then we construct rectangle R with diagonal PQ and sides parallel to coordinate axes. Task is to find a chance that whole rectangle R lays inside the circle.

At first I spent lots of time reasoning about line segment and circle intersection calculation but then I came up with thought that it's a huge overkill.
Because that is enough to just check two other vertexes of the rectangle. (if point Q occurred to be near circle border, one of the adjacent vertexes going to be outside the circle)

So all what we have to check, that none of those vertexes lies outside:
$\{Q_x^2+P_y^2 \le 1\}$
$\{P_x^2+Q_y^2 \le 1\}$
But having figured out geometrical side of a problem, I got stuck with statistical one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a hint:  for a fixed point $P = (x_0, y_0)$ on the boundary and some $Q$ in the interior of the unit circle, the rectangle with sides parallel to the coordinate axes with diagonal $PQ$ is contained in the circle if $Q$ is a point inside the inscribed rectangle with coordinates $\{(\pm x_0, \pm y_0)\}$.  Thus, parametrize the point $P$ as a function of an angle $\theta$ with respect to the coordinate axes, and calculate an integral of the form $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} \frac{A(\theta)}{\pi} \, d\theta,$$ where $A$ is the area of the inscribed rectangle as a function of $\theta$.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that sides parallel to coordinate axises is mine case. Already fixed the question.

It's a nice idea about Q being inside of the $\{(\pm x_0,\pm y_0)\}$. Thought, It looks like that neends proof.
But then, I see no reason to do any integral calculation. chance would be just $\frac {area\: of\: \{(\pm x_0,\pm y_0)\}} { area\: of\: circle}$. Am I right?

Comment: The integral is necessary.  The expression you wrote is a function of $(x_0, y_0)$ which is in turn a function of $\theta$ on $[0,2\pi)$--that is to say, it is a conditional probability given that $P$ is a fixed point.  The desired probability is unconditional and **must** be integrated over the distribution of $P$ on the circle's boundary.

Comment: Maybe one can find an answer that does not require calculation, but I would go ahead and integrate, perhaps only from $0$ to $\pi/2$.

Comment: I am not sure that I got it right, so I will write it here as a comment.  Suppose $x = r \cdot \cos (\theta)$ and $y = r \cdot \sin (\theta)$ Then, $\frac {S_{rect}} {S_{circle}} = \frac {4 \cdot r^2 \cdot \cos (\theta) \sin (\theta)} {\pi \cdot r^2}$

Comment: @AndréNicolas we will compute $ \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2} S_{rect}/S_{circle}\:d\theta$, which results in $\frac \pi 4 \int_{\theta=0}^{pi/2}\:(\sin(\theta) - \frac \theta 2 - \frac {\sin(2\theta)} {4}  )\:d\theta$, which is approximately equals 0,27. Is that correct?

Comment: I can't mark it as correct answer till I am sure that solution described above by me and derived from heropup's answer is correct.

Comment: I get $\frac{4}{\pi^2}$.